# How to deal with logging and unit test coverage?

Tags: junit, log4j, line, code-coverage

Any idea how to approach this issue:

- I have classes with a lot of unit tests
- Those classes use Log4j with following levels: DEBUG, INFO, ERROR

When I simply run unit test and calculate coverage depending on the configuration I will not get through all the logging statements. I use `if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) ...`

- I have already had problems in the past when application started to fail on production, and we changed the log level do DEBUG to get more insight, but this caused `NullPointerException`s (bad coding of course)
- In theory we can run all the tests with different levels of logging.

Any smart way to do it or any tools that help to solve this issue?

Comment: Why not just run your testsuite in `DEBUG` level?

Comment: Well, use a test-specific log4j configuration that sets the level to DEBUG.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in comments:

> use a test-specific log4j configuration that sets the level to DEBUG.

You also mention:

> we changed the log level do DEBUG to get more insight, but this caused `NullPointerException`s

That sounds like a bug. Identifying bugs like this is the whole point of tests: now you can fix them.